# How to configure Gridlines that "overflow"

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to configure the grid that it overflows?

It should look like this:

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a feature, but you might look at invoking [`drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) in the renderer's [`drawRangeGridline()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/AbstractCategoryItemRenderer.html#drawRangeGridline%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot,%20org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20double%29) method, seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/AbstractCategoryItemRenderer.html#line.763). The [baseline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) coordinates should be near `(dataArea.getMinX(), v)`, although I haven't tried it.